# Safari and cookies in iframe

Tags: javascript, cookies

Safari browser blocks 3rd party cookies by default.

I have site A (main site) that loads site B (framed site) in the iframe. Site B sets some cookies ( WHEN THE USER CLICK A BUTTON ), to function properly. These cookies are called 3rd party cookies, as they are not set by site A.

So I found this solution: https://github.com/vitr/safari-cookie-in-iframe

But in my case it doesn't work because to set the cookie, the user first has to click a button.

The framed.html is infact like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Framed Page</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color: lightcoral;">
<h2>This is the framed site</h2>

<div border="0" class="cookie_button" id="continue_button" onclick="SetCookie('cookieAcceptanceCookie','accepted',9999);">accept</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a solution to my problem?

Comment: _“But in my case it doesn't work because to set the cookie, the user first has to click a button.”_ - and how exactly is that keeping you from doing the same thing as described in that article …? Whether you automatically redirect to that other domain, or do it only when the click has happened - what’s the difference?

Comment: If you are concerned that it interrupts the flow too much, then you either need to do it upfront (even if the user should afterwards not be interested in that functionality), or you could do it via a popup maybe. That the 3rd-party domain is visited “as a 1st-party” is the important thing here; whether that is via a redirect in the current window, or in an outside context such as a popup, should not really matter. (Whether the popup blocker might give you more trouble in the specific situation might be a different question.)

Answer (score 4):

The only workaround that worked for me is redirecting through the iframed domain once.

So, if you have abc.com and xyz.com is an iframe under abc.com, while landing to the abc.com, there needs to be an intermediate redirect through xyz.com only for the purpose of setting a blank cookie. Then Safari will allow setting a cookie from iframe for xyz.com.

I'm not sure if there's any other better workaround. However, this worked and served my purpose.

Thanks.

Comment: You saved my day.

Comment: Its not working anymore on safari 13+. Its blocking cookies anyways .

Comment: Have you found the solution to this problem by now?  Please share the sample code.

Comment: Yes Safari 13.1.1 is blocking this approach.

Answer (score 2):

Safari now blocks all third party cookies. You can only use the Storage API to try to get user access to their third party cookies.

https://www.infoq.com/news/2020/04/safari-third-party-cookies-block/